# How to create variables in typed actors?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

Is this the correct way to create local actor variables with Akka Typed (see the `var` named `state`)?

Example:

```
object Main {
  def behavior(name: String): Behavior[String] = {
    var state = s"$name's state."
    Static {
      case str: String =>
        println(s"$name: Updating state.")
        state = state + str
        println(s"$name: State is now $state")
    }

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def mainBe: Behavior[String] =
      ContextAware {
        context =>
          val a1 = context.spawn(Props(behavior("Actor 1")), "actor-1")
          val a2 = context.spawn(Props(behavior("Actor 2")), "actor-2")
          Static {
            case str =>
              a1 ! str + "(1)"
              a2 ! str + "(2)"
          }

      }


    val system = ActorSystem("Tester", Props(mainBe))
    system ! "John"
    system ! "Smith"
    Await.result(system.whenTerminated, 1 second)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Actor 1: Updating state.
Actor 2: Updating state.
Actor 1: State is now Actor 1's state.John(1)
Actor 2: State is now Actor 2's state.John(2)
Actor 1: Updating state.
Actor 2: Updating state.
Actor 1: State is now Actor 1's state.John(1)Smith(1)
Actor 2: State is now Actor 2's state.John(2)Smith(2)
```

Comment: You need to give a lot more info about *how* you "create two actors based on this behaviour".

Comment: @Shadowlands Fixed. It seems it works if I run it with a simpler program! Had to reword the question as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way to do this. But it is not always preferable to rely upon mutable variables, in many cases the performance overhead of having to allocate a new Behavior is less important than the improved resilience against simple programming mistakes that immutable behaviors give you. Your example would look like:

```
def behavior(name: String) = behavior(name, s"$name’s state.")
def behavior(name: String, state: String): Behavior[String] =
  Total { str =>
    println(s"$name: Updating state.")
    val nextState = state + str
    println(s"$name: State is now $nextState")
    behavior(name, nextState)
  }
```

Being unable to update a reference with a new value means that the compiler will restrict what you can do wrong (like updating twice or not at all).

Comment: Very interesting! Why are you using `Total` here and not `Static`? Oh wait.. static always goes to the `Same` right?